# BizTalk ESB ToolKit 2.2 Installation

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Mistakenly I uninstalled the ESB ToolKit 2.2 using add/remove program. How can I install that again.When I tried to install it from Microsoft Server 2013-> setup.exe file. It shows me error like

[image]

And when I try to download from Microsoft, it gives these files I dont know which will help in installation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The installation files for the ESB Toolkit 2.2 can be found on the BizTalk 2013 R2 installation media.

> On the BizTalk Server installation Start screen, click Install
>   ​Microsoft BizTalk ESB Toolkit.

Complete install and configuration guide can be found on MSDN: [Install and Configure the Microsoft BizTalk ESB Toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj684558.aspx)